# how to use the mydelivengo api?

Tags: c#, api, rest, get, token

I have a project to use in C# the tool MyDelivengo in order to send some packages by post.
MyDelivengo offers API to automate the sendings. But I never use API in C#...
The example in MyDelivengo is
GET https://mydelivengo.laposte.fr/api/v2.3/envois
API-Authorization: Oono8eez7eez9NRZ3xaeFaeh8hee3u
User-Agent: Guzzle/4.0 curl/7.21.4 PHP/5.5.7

Could you help me to create a sample in C# To Send this URL and retrieve information?

Thank you

Regards

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, I see you're new here and as such I recommend taking the [tour] and reading the [help], especially the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. With that being said, check out [Microsoft's "tutorial"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) as well as the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) class documentation

Comment: Before you start with C#, go and find/download postman, and see if you can make it work there.